# How can I fail Maven build if surefire:test goal fails?

Tags: jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

How can I fail Maven build if surefire:test goal fails?   I am asking this question in the context of running tests, excuted by Maven Surefire, on Jenkins.   Currently, if 1 or all tests fail, Jenkins reports "unstable build" instead of a red error.   How can I override this and tell Maven to return a failure exit code if 1 or more tests fail?   I want Jenkins to report a RED icon instead of a YELLOW icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate your compile and test phases, using the [post-build task plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task).  That has an option "Escalate script execution status to job status", which will do what you want.  So you might use goal `compile` or `process-test-classes` for your build, and your post-build task would be `mvn verify` with the escalate option turned on.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the legend button of your Jenkins instance ( main view, lower right corner), it'll show you something like https://builds.apache.org/legend
In general: red is compilation error(fatal), yellow means failing tests. So those colors have different meanings, which should help you to identify the problem.
The actual question is: Why do you want yellow to be red?

Comment: Simple answer:  this particular test suite is critical and should not allow a single error.   I just want to override the default behavior of the Jenkins maven plugin, running a JUnit test, and force a exit code of 1 when there is 1 or more assertion failures ( im not talking about exceptions here) , just like I can in any shell script that I run in a Jenkins job.

Comment: So in the end it's just a visual thing. Although I wouldn't recommend the adjustment, you can do it with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin

Comment: Nice suggestion.  I think that will work.  I'll try it.

Comment: I don't want "yellow to be red". I want to set a higher bar. "Yellow" means caution, and I'm fine with Yellow meaning caution. A failing test, however, means that the code doesn't work. This isn't "caution". This is "this thing could delete all your files for all we know". "It compiled" is a very low bar. I understand that many developers work in an environment of constantly failing tests (or no tests at all). Our team does TDD and has zero tolerance for failing tests.

Comment: Please read http://javaadventure.blogspot.nl/2013/11/jenkins-maven-job-type-considered-evil.html . The problem is that with a Maven job, Jenkins nests itself inside Maven and the surefire-plugin. And that changes the behavior when tests fail.